# How to make sidebar fixed without setting fixed property

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, next.js

So I am trying to make fixed sidebar because my main content page has a lot of content that it's going down by scrolling page. And my sidebar is already set to relative because he can be resizable(e.g can have 2 fifferent 'width' values depending if user clicks to open or close it).
[Wrong layout of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNLJ5.png)

Maybe someone had familiar problem. What general recommendations could you give?

I was trying to make sidebar fixed instead of relative but then i can't resize it. So relative property must stay.

Comment: Share some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.